# Windows Server 2012 Password Experation GPO Not Applying

Tags: windows-7, passwords, windows-server-2012, group-policy

We have a single DC and are trying to enforce Password Policies to all of our computers.  We're trying to change it from the default 42 day max password age to 120 or so.  The policy appears to be set on our computers, however it's not actually working.  Our users end up changing their password every 30 days or so, no matter what GPO says.  We only have one GPO that is setting the password policies.

When I do a net user username on a user that had to change their password today it shows they shouldn't have to change it again until 4/8/15 and said 3/something last month when they had to change their password.

Any ideas as to why the 120 day password expiration is not working?

Password Policy:

> Enforce password history 6 passwords remembered
>
> Maximum password age 120 days
>
> Minimum password age 1 days
>
> Minimum password length 7 characters
>
> Password must meet complexity requirements Disabled
>
> Store passwords using reversible encryption Disabled

Account Lockout Policy:

> Account lockout duration 5 minutes
>
> Account lockout threshold 20 invalid logon attempts
>
> Reset account lockout counter after 5 minutes

Comment: It seems to be every 30, though the original setting was 42 which has been bumped to 120 for a few months now.

Comment: Don't forget user password policies are set on the user portion of Group Policy and you have to attach the policy to an OU containing the users you want the policy to apply to... I accidentally tapped to submit. Sorry!

Comment: I'm not aware of any password policies under users.  Only Computer/Policies/Windows/Security/Account/Password.  This path does not exist on the user side of things.  So does it have to be set at the OU level and not the DC level?  I currently have it linked to our domain that has multiple OU's. (It's enabled and enforced, of course)

Comment: How can I get those values and modify ***programmatically*** using C# and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By creating GPO on OU,
This will not work for what you're trying to do. GPOs pertaining to Password policies can only be set at the domain level. 
However,
In order to apply a policy to a subset of domain users then you need to use Fine-Grained password policies.

These can be applied at the group level, so you need to ensure all the users you wish to affect with this new policy are a member of the appropriate group.

To do this on a Windows 2012 domain, do the following from a DC .

1. From the Start Screen type DSAC.EXE to start the Directory Service
   Administrative Center.
2. Navigate to the System\Password Settings Container
3. Right Click and select New or use New under the Tasks menu.
4. Choose Password Settings
5. Create a New Password policy either for a User or a group.
6. Set its Precedence in case if u have multiple policies
       created, so lower the number higher the priority.

It's fairly self-explanatory from there.

Comment: You sir. You just made me giddy with excitement. I never knew this program ever existed. Thank you so much!